# Update varbinary column with latest file using filepath column from record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, bulk-load, varbinarymax

I am trying to update a series of Document_Files that are stored in the following table.

**Document_File**:

- FileID int
- TypeID int
- FilePath nvarchar(255)
- FileData varbinary(max)

I am trying to update the `FileData` column for each record of a specific type using the `FilePath` to locate the BLOB to be imported.

I can update them one at a time using the following:

```
UPDATE Document_File
SET FileData = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'C:\Reports\Report - District1.xlsx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T)
    WHERE FileID = 123456
```

I've attempted to loop through the series of records of the desired file type using the following:

```
DECLARE @MyFile varchar(100)
DECLARE @LoopCounter int
DECLARE @FileID varchar(255)
DECLARE @isExists int

SET @LoopCounter = (SELECT COUNT(FilePath) FROM Document_File WHERE TypeID = 123)
SET @FileID = (SELECT TOP 1 FileID FROM Document_File WHERE TypeID = 123) -1

WHILE @LoopCounter > 0
BEGIN
    SET @MyFile = (SELECT TOP 1 FilePath FROM Document_File WHERE TypeID = 123 
        AND FileID > @FileID)
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @MyFile, @isExists OUTPUT

    IF(@isExists = 1)
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN
                UPDATE Document_File
                SET FileData = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'@MyFile', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T)
                WHERE TypeID = 123 AND FileID > @FileID
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            END
        END CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN
    END 

SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter -1
SET @FileID = @FileID +1

END
```

I am getting an error stating:

> Cannot bulk load. The file "@MyFile" does not exist

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and if there is a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`OPENROWSET` doesn't accept parameters so your line:

```
(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'@MyFile', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

fails, both because you've quoted the parameter name, and because `OPENROWSET` doesn't allow parameters.

For this approach to work you have to use dynamic SQL, i.e. dynamically build the SQL string and then execute it.

Here is an [example](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic982066-338-1.aspx).

Comment: Yes this works for capturing the varbinary data but I can't seems to pass it into an UPDATE statement.

Comment: I've only shown you the select part of your update, you can make your entire update statement dynamic. If that is what you have tried to do please post your code.